# JSP - In Eclipse, getting several errors using MySQL backend

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp

Trying to create a simple login using MySQL.  I'm getting everal errors, and wondering if you guys can help. I'm a super newbie at JSP and programming (DBA by trade). I have added the errors on the line, and am getting error 500s when I try to run the code within Eclipse.

```
    <%@ page import="java.sql.Date, java.sql.PreparedStatement, java.sql.ResultSet, java.sql.SQLException, java.sql.Statement, java.sql.Timestamp, java.text.SimpleDateFormat, 
java.util.ArrayList, java.util.Calendar, java.util.HashMap, java.util.List, java.util.Map, java.util.Map.Entry, java.sql.*" %>


<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Login</title>

</head>

<body>

<%! String userdbName;

String userdbPsw;

String dbUsertype;

%>

<%

Connection con= null; //Connection cannot be resolved to a type

PreparedStatement ps = null; //PreparedStatement cannot be resolved to a type

ResultSet rs = null; //ResultSet cannot be resolved to a type



String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/record";

String user = "root";

String dbpsw = "root";



String sql = "select * from userdetail where name=? and password=? and usertype=?";



String name = request.getParameter("name");

String password = request.getParameter("password");

String usertype = request.getParameter("usertype");



if((!(name.equals(null) || name.equals("")) && !(password.equals(null) || 
password.equals(""))) && !usertype.equals("select"))

{

try{

Class.forName(driverName);
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, dbpsw); //DriverManager cannot be resolved (x2?)

ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

ps.setString(1, name);

ps.setString(2, password);

ps.setString(3, usertype);

rs = ps.executeQuery();

if(rs.next())

{ 

userdbName = rs.getString("name");

userdbPsw = rs.getString("password");

dbUsertype = rs.getString("usertype");

if(name.equals(userdbName) && password.equals(userdbPsw) && usertype.equals(dbUsertype))

{

session.setAttribute("name",userdbName);

session.setAttribute("usertype", dbUsertype); 

response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp"); 

} 

}

else

response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");

rs.close();

ps.close(); 

}

catch(SQLException sqe) //SQLException cannot be resolved to a type (x2)

{

out.println(sqe);

} 

}

else

{

%>

<center><p style="color:red">Error In Login</p></center>

<% 

getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp").include(request, 
response);

}

%>

</body>

</html>
```

This code returns the following error:

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
>
> Type Exception Report
>
> Message An exception occurred processing JSP page /Login.jsp at line
>   56
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred
>   processing JSP page /Login.jsp at line 56
>
> 53:  54:  55:  56: if((!(name.equals(null) || name.equals("")) &&
>   !(password.equals(null) ||  57: password.equals(""))) &&
>   !usertype.equals("select")) 58:  59: {
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> Root Cause java.lang.NullPointerException
>     org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:192)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
>   logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the issue with import, to import java classes in JSP use for example
`<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>` or for multiple imports use

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List,java.util.Date,....,java.util.ArrayList" %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still getting errors. I have updated the code with what I chagned as well as the error.

Comment: Modify the if statement as this one if((!(null==name || name.isEmpty()) && !(null==password || 
password.isEmpty())) && !usertype.equals("select"))

Comment: That worked, but now for some reason I am gettingHTTP Status 404 – Not Found


Type Status Report

Message /Javadiscover/login.jsp

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.


Apache Tomcat/8.5.14

Comment: Here solutions that I've tried so far 

Right-click project -> properties -> Project Facets -> Runtimes -> checked "Apache Tomcat v9.0" -> Apply -> finish.

Server tab -> Right-click "Tomcat v9.0..." -> properties -> switch location -> Choose "Use tomcat installation" on "Server locations" panel.